# How to select calls, answers, deals, rate and etc. by working time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select calls, answers, deals, rate, talking_time by the grouped working time.

Here is my select:

```
SELECT
    users.username as username,
    DATE_FORMAT(users_worktime.start,'%Y-%m-%d') as start,
    SUM(users_worktime.length) as working_time
FROM
    users_worktime
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = users_worktime.user_id 
WHERE 1
    AND users_worktime.user_id = '8'
    AND users_worktime.start >= '2015-12-30 00:00:00'
    AND users_worktime.start <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    DAY(users_worktime.start)
```

It's all good, i got 2 rows by date 2015-12-30 and 2015-12-31:

```
| username | start       | working_time |
-----------------------------------------
| Haroldas | 2015-12-30  | 85.00        | 
| Haroldas | 2015-12-31  | 170.00       |
```

And my question: how to select COUNT calls from table calls, answers - SUM all calls where status = 'ended', select COUNT deals from table orders, rate - Deals / SUM calls, and talking_time - calls.call_length. And all of these select by the grouped working time.

I need result like this:

```
| username | start       | calls | answers | deals | rate | talking_time| working_time |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Haroldas | 2015-12-30  | 1     | 1       | 1     | 100% | 35          | 85.00        | 
| Haroldas | 2015-12-31  | 3     | 2       | 1     | 50%  | 160         | 170.00       |
```

And here are my data tables:

users_worktime:

```
| id | user_id | length | start               |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 8       | 30     | 2015-12-30 07:53:38 |
| 2  | 8       | 55     | 2015-12-30 12:53:38 |
| 3  | 8       | 170    | 2015-12-31 22:53:38 |
```

users:

```
| id | username |
-----------------
| 8  | Haroldas |
```

calls:

```
| id | user_id | order_id | status  | call_length | created_at          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 8       | 3        | ended   | 35          | 2015-12-30 07:53:38 |
| 2  | 8       | 4        | ended   | 100         | 2015-12-31 12:53:38 |
| 3  | 8       | NULL     | started | 15          | 2015-12-31 14:53:38 |
| 4  | 8       | NULL     | ended   | 45          | 2015-12-31 20:53:38 |
```

orders:

```
| id | user_id | call_id | start              |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3  | 8       |1       | 2015-12-30 07:53:38 |
| 4  | 8       |2       | 2015-12-31 12:53:38 |
```

How many calls / answers / deals / etc / were when user Haroldas working on these days.

Thank you

Comment: You could try with sub-selects in the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **subqueries** to achive your goal. I've also changed your base query because you'll not see records if user didn't work at specified period of time.

```
SELECT T2.*,
   (deals / answers_cnt) * 100 AS rate
FROM
(SELECT T.username,
       T.day_start
       SUM(T.working_time) AS working_time,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls AS C 
        WHERE DATE(created_at) = T.day_start
                  AND C.user_id = T.user_id) AS calls_cnt,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calls AS C 
        WHERE DATE(created_at) = T.day_start
                  AND C.user_id = T.user_id
                  AND C.status = 'ended') AS answers_cnt,
        (SELECT SUM(call_length) FROM calls AS C 
        WHERE DATE(created_at) = T.day_start
                  AND C.user_id = T.user_id) AS talking_time,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders AS O
         WHERE DATE(O.start) = T.day_start
                   AND O.user_id = T.user_id) AS deals_cnt         
FROM
    (SELECT U.username,
            U.id AS user_id,
            DATE(UW.start) as day_start,
            UW.length AS working_time       
    FROM users AS U
        LEFT JOIN users_worktime AS UW ON UW.user_id = U.id
    WHERE U.id = 8
              AND UW.start >= '2015-12-30 00:00:00'
              AND UW.start <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59') AS T
GROUP BY T.username, T.user_id, T.day_start
) AS T2
```

Comment: fabulaspb you are boss! It works. I have only question: now columns day_start show me a days 30 and 31. How to show full dates like 2015-12-30 and 2015-12-31? thank you

Comment: I modified my query.

Answer (score 1):

You can LEFT JOIN by user_id plus DAY of time. E.g.

```
FROM
users_worktime
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = users_worktime.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = calls.user_id 
               AND DAY(users_worktime.start)=DAY(calls.created_at)
```

Then apply all necessary aggregate functions to the `calls` data